# Migrating NUMBER from Oracle Enterprise to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle, type-conversion, numbers

We are in the process of evaluating a migration from Oracle Enterprise Edition to Postgresql.  One of the most used datatypes we use is NUMBER (unrestricted - No precision/No scale).

I am looking at orafce and I do not see an implementation of NUMBER even though I see implementations for DATE and VARCHAR2.  Does anyone know if there is a reason why NUMBER was not implemented in the extension?

Does anyone know if is possible to redefine using a Domain?  I tried the following and basic testing gave good results:

CREATE DOMAIN NUMBER AS BIGINT;

CREATE TABLE A_NUMBER_TABLE(A_NUMBER NUMBER);

template1=# INSERT INTO A_NUMBER_TABLE VALUES(12222222222222222);
INSERT 0 1

I got what I expected, but I am not sure it is good enough.

This seems too simple.  Does anyone have any input on this topic?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Why not just use [Numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) from Postgres?

Comment: We are migrating from Oracle, so we are talking about changing 10000+ places where we use NUMBER, this includes DDL, PL/SQL and embedded C code.  It would be nice if we could just introduce a type (domain) which automatically makes all those work.

Comment: I can see that, but if you are creating a `NUMBER` domain `numeric` would be the better choice as 1) It more closely matches `NUMBER`. 2) It has a greater range then `bigint` per the link I osted earlier.

Comment: Also have you looked at [Ora2Pg](https://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html) as it has [Column Type Control](https://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html#Column-type-control).

Comment: I know numeric has bigger range, but for my application BIGINT will suffice (we will never see a number > 9223372036854775807.  What I am trying to save is all the work needed to replace NUMBER in more that 10000 places..  I'll look at "Column Type Control" thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Consider the mathematical implications of the choice of type. `NUMERIC` preserves fractional parts when performing division, `BIGINT` does not. The following demonstrates this: `WITH x AS (SELECT 3::numeric AS n, 3::bigint AS i) SELECT x.n / 2 * 2, x.i / 2 * 2 FROM x;`. Which is consistent with the behavior of Oracle's `NUMBER` type? That should be the criteria for selecting how `NUMBER` is mapped to a PostgreSQL type.